# Java DatagramSocket doesn't receive data

Tags: java, networking, udp

I'm writing a simple client / server in java and I got this problem that I cannot fix.
    I'm using DatagramSocket on both client and server and my server just cannot receive any data. I don't get any errors but it just doesn't work.

Here is my source code for server:

```
public class GameServer {

    public static final String serverBuild = "0.00 (050319.milestone0-main)";
    public static final String protocolBuild = "1";

    public DatagramSocket serverSocket;

    public boolean isRunning = false;
    public Thread clientHandler;

    public GameServer(int port, String serverName) {
        System.out.println("Server> Starting a server on port: " + port + ".");
        System.out.println("Server> " + serverName + " running on server build " + serverBuild + ".");
        System.out.println("Server> Using protocol ID: " + protocolBuild + ".");

        isRunning = true;
        try {
            serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(port);
        }catch(Exception ex) {
            System.out.print("Server> ");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        clientHandler();
    }

    public void clientHandler() {
        clientHandler = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {

                while(isRunning) {
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
                    DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);

                    try {
                        serverSocket.receive(packet);
                        System.out.println("Server> " + new String(packet.getData(), 0, packet.getData().length));

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        System.out.print("Server> ");
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }

            }

        });
        clientHandler.start();
    }

}
```

Here is my source code for client:

```
    public class GameClient {

    public GameClient() {

        try {

            DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(25567);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length, InetAddress.getByName("192.168.0.24"), 25567);
            socket.send(packet);

        }catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Client is very simple because I was looking why my server doesn't work.

Comment: What is the value of `port` in the server? And what is the server host's IP address? And why are you using the same port for server and client in the client?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The console does not print anything, because the client sends the package is an empty array. The server is work right.

Comment: This answer doesn't have any use. Would you mind to explain what was wrong with OP's code?

Comment: @maio290 bad questions beget bad answers... the question should be flagged as off-topic.

Comment: @maio290 The code about the Client is different. socket.connect()

Comment: It is not an empty array. It is a 256-element array full of nulls. Not the same thing.

Comment: I mean every byte in the array is '', so do not print on console.  You can try String.getbytes() to replace buffer and then check the result.